# Parsing .ply files without memory leaks

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry, mesh, ply-file-format

I downloaded the .ply files in the [Stanford 3D scanning repository](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/data/3Dscanrep/), and am using Stanford's code from that page (ply.h, plyfile.c) to parse them. However, looking at this code, I see that it's rife with mallocs that are never freed. I could close my eyes and look the other way, but it makes my teeth itch.

I can think of two workarounds:

One is to use Hans Boehm's garbage collector, or something similar, which redefines "malloc" so that it does so within a garbage collector. I've never used this library, but perhaps there's a way to have it operate just on the mallocs in the Stanford code and not anywhere else.

The other workaround is to use a different parser, preferably a C++ one with nicely RAII-ified memory management. I see a few alternative parsers and converters listed at the above link, but rather than kill a day or two trying them all, I was hoping to get a recommendation here.

Can anybody recommend a way to parse .ply files without memory leaks, either by containing the memory leaks in the Stanford parser, or using a different parser, or by some third method I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also [RPly](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/rply/).

Answer (score 0):

This library looks promising; until someone else answers this question, I'll mark this as the answer: http://assimp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Another library is the one used by [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net)

http://vcg.sourceforge.net/index.php/Tutorial